# press more than one Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i was wondering if you could make it so you could have more that one button pressed at a time?

Like:

```
from Tkinter import *
tkwin = Tk()
def delayedDoSomethings():
    for i in range(1,10000000):
        print 'hi',i
def delayedDoSomething():
       for i in range(1,10000000):
           print i

a = Button(tkwin, text="Go", command=delayedDoSomething)
a.pack()
b = Button(tkwin, text="Go hi", command=delayedDoSomethings)
b.pack()
tkwin.mainloop()
```

and the i would be able to click "go" and then "go hi" but i cant because the window freezes until it is done. does any one know how to make it so that you can press more that one button at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is to use threads. Threads allow you to have multiple pieces of code executing at the same time (or they will at least *appear* to be executing simultaneously)

Inside of `delayedDoSomethings()`, you'll want to spawn a new thread that does the actual work, so that you can return control to Tkinter in the main thread.

You would do the same thing in `delayedDoSomething()`.

Here's some actual code that you could use in delayedDoSomethings()

```
def delayedDoSomethings():
    def work():
        for i in rance(1, 10000000):
            print 'hi',i
    import thread
    thread.start_new_thread(separateThread, ()) #run the work function in a separate thread.
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#module-thread) is the documentation for Python's built-in thread module, which will be useful.

Comment: only one thing though i think that import thread should be at the top along with all imports ever